# Как затемнить или заблокировать экран, как в телефонном разговоре?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

У меня есть страница звонков, на которой пользователь прикладывает телефон к уху , я нашел как реализовать датчик приближения Proximity. К сожалению я не могу понять , как блокировать эран. Я пробывала просто убирать элементы с экрана (менять свойство isVisible), но это не совсем то. Когда происходит событие OnSensorChanged Надо как то поменять свойства экрана , что бы было как на обычных звонках.

```
using Android.App;
    using Android.Content;
    using Android.Content.PM;
    using Android.Hardware;
    using Android.OS;
    using Android.Runtime;
    using Android.Views;
    using Android.Widget;
    using Corporate_messenger.DB;
    using Corporate_messenger.Service;
    using Corporate_messenger.Service.Notification;
    using Newtonsoft.Json;
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using Xamarin.Forms;
    
    namespace Corporate_messenger.Droid
    {
        [Activity(Label = "CallActivity",ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait)]
        public class CallActivity : Activity, ISensorEventListener
        {
    
            Android.Widget.Button BtnStartCall;
            Android.Widget.Button BtnEndCall;
            Android.Widget.Button BtnEndCallCenter;
    
            SensorManager sensorManager;
            Sensor proximitySensor;
    
      
            protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
            {
                base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
     
                    sensorManager = (SensorManager) GetSystemService(Context.SensorService);
                    sensorManager.RegisterListener(this, sensorManager.GetDefaultSensor(SensorType.Proximity), SensorDelay.Ui);
                    proximitySensor = sensorManager.GetDefaultSensor(SensorType.Proximity);
            }
    
          
    
            public void OnAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, [GeneratedEnum] SensorStatus accuracy)
            {
                var s = sensor;
            }
    
            public void OnSensorChanged(SensorEvent e)
            {
              
// The sensor is triggered here, at this moment I can’t figure out how to Hide the screen (do not
               // active , darken)
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

решение было найдено, в методе OnCreate надо инициализировать следующее

```
 SensorManager _sm;
 Sensor proximity;
 protected override async  void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
  _sm = (SensorManager)this.GetSystemService(SensorService);
            if (_sm.GetSensorList(SensorType.Proximity).Count != 0)
            {
                proximity = _sm.GetDefaultSensor(SensorType.Proximity);
                _sm.RegisterListener(this, proximity, SensorDelay.Normal);
            }
}
```

В методе OnSensorChanged

```
public void OnSensorChanged(SensorEvent e)
        {
           
                if (mWakeLock == null)
                {
                    mWakeLock = mPowerManager.NewWakeLock(WakeLockFlags.ProximityScreenOff, "incall");
                    mWakeLock.Acquire();
                   
                }
                Sensor = false;
 
        }
```

мы регистрируем сенсор  `_sm.RegisterListener(this, proximity, SensorDelay.Normal);`  поэтому когда вы выходите с окна обязательно снимите регистрацию , что бы `OnSensorChanged` выключился , так же на вызвать метод  `mWakeLock.Acquire();`
вот так я это реализовала

```
 if (null != mWakeLock)
            {
                mWakeLock.Release();
                mWakeLock = null;
            }
            _sm.UnregisterListener(this, proximity);
```